# Xcode: How to find which cell has no reuse identifier

Tags: swift, uitableview, reuseidentifier

I have this warning:

Prototype table cells must have reuse identifiers

The project is pretty large and we have many `tableViews` and I cannot find the cell that causes this warning. Is there a way to find the source of this warning? I can see the storyboard being the `Friends.Storyboard` but all the cells there have an id.

[image]

Comment: Open Storyboard as `Open As/Source Code` (left clic on it). You should see a the storyboard as XML then.Look for `<tableViewCell` and in the same XML attribute/tag, the one which doesn't have a `reuseIdentifier="someID"`. You could use a regex also in that XML.

Comment: @Larme That should be an answer.

Answer (score 4):

1. Build your project (so the warning is generated)
2. Go to the Report Navigator
3. Click on the build log with the warning

[image]

4. Expand the warning in the build log
5. You will now see the id(s) of the offending cell(s)

[image]

6. Use 'Find in Project' to search your project for the id(s) you just found.
7. Click on the result that is returned

[image]

8. The storyboard will open with the correct cell selected and you can add the reuse identifier

Comment: Glad it helped. If this is the answer you used to solve your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

Open `Friends.storyboard` with Left Clic: *Open As/Source Code*.
You should see now the `Friends.storyboard` as a XML File.

I create specially a `UITableView`, with two cells, one with an reuse identifier, and another one without one:

```
<prototypes>
    <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="thisID" id="rXT-Vv-RiK">
        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="327" height="44"/>
        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
        <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="rXT-Vv-RiK" id="o6B-Eq-gDX">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="327" height="43.5"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
        </tableViewCellContentView>
    </tableViewCell>
    <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" id="R2l-ad-LaA">
        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="72" width="327" height="44"/>
        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
        <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="R2l-ad-LaA" id="zNB-8w-4eM">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="327" height="43.5"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
        </tableViewCellContentView>
    </tableViewCell>
</prototypes>
```

Simplified (pointing out what to look for):

```
...
<tableViewCell ... reuseIdentifier="thisID" ...>
</tableViewCell>
<tableViewCell ...> //With no attribute/tag "reuseIdentifier"
</tableViewCell>
...
```

So looking for `<tableViewCell` should be a good start.
You could also use a RegularExpression, but that's maybe too much work (too much tests to check it) opposed to the usage a "manual" search.

Answer (score 1):

Heres another option if you don't mind using terminal and regex, it makes project-wide searching quite fast.

This makes use of `pcregrep` which is a version of grep that supports Perl Compatible Regular Expressions.

If you don't have pcregrep you can install it using brew:

```
brew install pcre
```

Once its installed you can cd into your project root and run this command in terminal, (Note the trailing `.`):

```
pcregrep -rnI --buffer-size=100000000 '^(.)*\btableViewCell \b((?!reuseIdentifier).)*$' .
```

It will list the file names and line numbers where a tableViewCell is declared and is missing a reuse identifier.

It prints out results in the terminal like this:

```
// this is the terminal prompt and the command we entered to search
myUser$ pcregrep -rnI --buffer-size=10000000000 '^(.)*\btableViewCell \b((?!reuseIdentifier).)*$' .

// This is the path to the matched file, followed by the line number with the match, followed by a preview of the matched line
./MyProject/Source/UI/MyController/Base.lproj/MyAccountTableViewCell.xib:13:        <tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" rowHeight="71" id="B6A-LV-CH7" customClass="MyAccountTableViewCell">
```

An explanation:

- pcregrep - The program that will be parsing source files looking for matches.
- -rnI - (r) search recursively - (n) print line number in file of match. (I) ignore binary files.
- --buffer-size=100000000 - sets a larger buffer for parsing larger files. (was necessary for some files in my projects)

Regex: ^(.)*\btableViewCell \b((?!reuseIdentifier).)*$

- ^ - match position at start of line
- (.)* - match anything at the start of the line unlimited times
- \btableViewCell \b - match the word 'tableViewCell ' with trailing space exactly
- ((?!reuseIdentifier).) - match lines where 'reuseIdentifier' is not found
- *$ - followed by any text and the end of the line

Comment: I had to run `pcre2grep` instead of `pcregrep` since the latter crashed with a segmentation fault, but otherwise your solution worked perfectly.